# keep a div visible without scrolling when inner div has max-height set

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a #container div inside which i have a textbox and another div #toolbar. The container div can be placed at any height of the screen on user click. The textbox has a max-height set to 75% of the screen ht. On adding text, the textbox height increases but when it reaches the bottom of the page, the toolbar div gets hidden and i have to scroll down the page to see the toolbar. I want that on adding text, the whole container should be always visible along with srollable textbox.

Here is the code that i have:

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#inputBox {
    height: 80%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 75vh;
}
#toolbar {
    height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div role="textbox" id="inputBox"></div>
    <div role="toolbar" id="toolbar"></div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions how to keep the whole container expand its height?

Comment: Make a js fiddle

Comment: I already see a scrollbar what's the issue I did not get:https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/hug2qavz/2/

Comment: something like this what your after aparna? https://jsfiddle.net/1em5j0q2/

Comment: What i want is that when i add text in the textbox on the go, the height expands (which is what i want) but on reaching the bottom of the page, the textbox height keeps expanding and is visible but the toolbar gets clipped at the bottom. I have to scroll down the page to see it. The fiddles show exactly what i want but unable to achieve in my code. Thanks!

Comment: @AparnaJain you may put yout full HTML code, want to check is there any other issue.

Comment: I figured it out. In my code this css won't work. But anyways, thanks for your support!